# Deciding if a collection is a set through comparing with a set

Tags: functions, logic, set-theory

If there is a bijection between a some set  *A* and some collection *B*, then I can deduce that *B* is a set?...

I have only work with *ZF* axioms, and recently, I have been thinking about this, but because I have only work with functions between sets, I don't know if my question has sense...

Really, I only want to find out when a collection must be a set through comparing with sets.

Comment: See [Axiom schema of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement)

Comment: Great! I don't know that axiom